# Get JSON value to TextView from HTTP post

Tags: java, android, json, http

I need to do an HTTP post with a cookie, and get the JSON response and put it in a TextView in Android Studio.

The code I have so far:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    new GetDataSync().execute();
    try {
        postPHP("Hoi");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 public class GetDataSync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            getData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}

private void postPHP (String cookie1) throws IOException, JSONException {

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    String cookieString = cookieManager.getCookie(cookie1);
    URL url = new URL("http://piggybank.wordmediavormgever.nl/getSaldo.php");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("thatsallfolks", cookieString);
    connection.connect();
    OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
    out.write(data);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}

private void getData() throws IOException, JSONException {
    TextView txtUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user);
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://piggybank.wordmediavormgever.nl/getSaldo.php");
    try {
        String response = json.getString("saldo");
        Log.e("saldo", response);
        response = json.getString("saldo");
        txtUser.setText(response);

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the JSON to TextView and HTTP POST request are two seperate pieces of code, that's why I don't get the correct JSON value. I need to combine the two so it first sends the cookie via POST and then puts the JSON response in a TextView, but I don't know how

Comment: Can you update your question with code showing how you are calling `getData` & `postPHP` ?

Comment: Sure, I have updated it.

Comment: use runonUIthread to set data .Since Textview is working on main thread and your asynctask is in background thread exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

**Change your code as follows:**

```
public class GetDataSync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private final String cookie;

        public GetDataSync(String cookie) {
            this.cookie = cookie;
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                postPHP();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return getData();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String resposne) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            TextView txtUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user);
            txtUser.setText(resposne);
        }

        private void postPHP () throws IOException, JSONException {

            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            String cookieString = cookieManager.getCookie(cookie);
            URL url = new URL("http://piggybank.wordmediavormgever.nl/getSaldo.php");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("thatsallfolks", cookieString);
            connection.connect();
            OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }

        private String getData()   {
            JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://piggybank.wordmediavormgever.nl/getSaldo.php");
            try {
                String response = json.getString("saldo");
                Log.e("saldo", response);
                response = json.getString("saldo");
                return response;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                return "";
            }
        }
}
```

Execute the task in `onCreate` as follows:

`new GetDataSync("Hoi").execute();`

Comment: I now get an unhandled exeptions warning for the return getData(); part.

Comment: @Roan Remove `throws ...` from your method. Refer the answer.